# AsyncApexJob: TotalJobItems != JobItemsProcessed + NumberOfErrors

Tags: batch, asyncapexjob

I'm running into an odd issue where [AsyncApexJobs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_asyncapexjob.htm) (from Batch Apex) are finishing with a status of "Complete" but the `TotalJobItems != JobItemsProcessed + NumberOfErrors`.

[image]

Should I be concerned that maybe Salesforce is dropping/losing 1 job?

Comment: oddly, when I look at apex jobs in setup, it is correct...

Comment: Based on this [later question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273750/total-number-of-batches-in-a-job-is-different-in-ui-and-soql), it looks like this is a Known Issue.