# Total number of batches in a job is different in UI and SOQL

Tags: apex, batch, jobs

Total Batches shown for a job in the APex Jobs page is different from TotalJobItems value in AsyncApexJob query.

In the UI:

[image]

In the Query:

[image]

In the query result, TotalJobItems != JobItemsProcessed + NumberOfErrors

In the UI, Total Batches == Batches Processed + Failures

As per Salesforce documentation, TotalJobItems' label is Total Batches. So I don't think I'm comparing two different things.

[image]

Has anyone noticed such behavior before? Should I consider this as somehow 10 batches are not being processed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is a known issue:

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XvaAAE

When a batch Apex job fails due to an internal Salesforce exception, the batch Apex framework will retry the operation a limited number of times before aborting the whole job upon repeated failures. Due to this only some batches are getting processed and the other remain unprocessed and this batch job is not marked aborted both in UI and backend.